# Amazon MQ Destinations Disappearing from ActiveMQ console

Tags: activemq-classic, amazon-mq

I am new to Amazon MQ and ActiveMQ in general. I have configured my broker to have a composite topic that forwards to multiple queues. I have 3 brokers setup this way. Two out of 3 are working as expected. The third though is acting strange. When I go to view my topics and queues the console is empty. I use an identical XML config file for all 3 brokers being the only difference is the topics and queues names. I think I have persistent mode enabled but not sure I have that setup exactly right. I simply uncommented this line in the XML.

```
<forcePersistencyModeBrokerPlugin persistenceFlag="true"/>
```

I also have the `<destinations>` section filled in with the topics and queues I want created upon restart of the broker. I have noticed that they might show up initially but will eventually disappear from the console unless we maintain messages being written to them. I'm not sure what to look for so hopefully someone can give me some guidance or direction.

Comment: I'll check but i don't think so. I'll comment back once i find out

Comment: It looks like i do and and it sounds like that will be the issue. I'll switch that to false and see if it helps. In production, we would likely leave it as true for resources but in non prod it's helpful to see all the topics and queues. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you aren't using `gcInactiveDestinations="true"` anywhere in your broker configuration as this will delete destinations that are inactive and remove them from the console view. You can read more about deleting inactive destinations in the [ActiveMQ documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/delete-inactive-destinations.html).